# How to cite theorems within a series of equations?

Tags: equations, citing, amsmath, theorems

I want to know if it's possible to cite theorems within series of equations, without interleaving text like "From Theorem 1.3, it follows that:". Here's an idea of the kind of formatting I'm looking for:

```
x = 1                                                (Theorem 1.1)
x^2 = 1                                              (Theorem 1.2)
x^2 - 1 = 0                                          (Theorem 1.3)
(x + 1)(x - 1) = 0                                   (Theorem 1.4)
x + 1 = 0                                            (Theorem 1.5)
1 + 1 = 0                                            (Theorem 1.6)
2 = 0                                                (Theorem 1.7)
```

I also want to be able to do this in a single long, chained equation. e.g. Intermixing it with the `align*` environment from amsmath:

```
expr1 = expr2                                        (Theorem 2.1)
      = expr3                                        (Theorem 2.2)
      = expr4                                        (Theorem 2.3)
      = expr5                                        (Theorem 2.4)
      = ...
```

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Yes it works. You can the the `flalign` environment for this, with the first column empty, the equations in the second column and the references in the last column.

Comment: @Bernard Sounds great. Can you provide an example via an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are 3 possible  layouts for references. `alignat` gives you full control on the spacing between the equations and the reference, whereas `flalign` puts references at the right margin:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[standard, amsmath, thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}\label{th:P}
  A powerful theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}\label{th:PP}
  Another powerful theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{flalign}
  & & a + b & = c + d + e& & \text{(by \cref{th:P})}\\
  & & a' + b' + e'& = c'+ d' & & \text{(by \cref{th:PP})}
\end{flalign}

\begin{align}
  a' + b' + e' & = c' + d' & & \text{(by \cref{th:PP})} \\
  a + b & = c + d + e & & \text{(by \cref{th:P})}
\end{align}

\begin{alignat}{2}
  a' + b' + e' & = c' + d' & \qquad & \text{(by \cref{th:PP})} \\
  a + b & = c + d + e & & \text{(by \cref{th:P})}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]